# Change link text in template based on referrer

Tags: django, jinja2, mezzanine

I'm making a navbar for my blog. If a reader arrives at a post from the post listing, I want the navigation link to say "Back to the post listing" or something like that. If the visitor comes from another source, I'd like the link to say "Read other posts like this one."

I know I can test the referrer with `request.META.HTTP_REFERER`, but I'm wondering what to compare this with. I could always hard-code a comparison to the post listing URL, but I'd prefer something more durable.

Answer (score 0):

A combination of `reverse()` and [`build_absolute_uri()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.build_absolute_uri) should do the trick:

```
if request.META['HTTP_REFERER'] == request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('posts')):
    ...
```

(This assumes that you have only a single URL mapping to the post list.)

Since you're using Jinja2 you could do this in the template as well.

Comment: Can't get this to work inside the jinja templates. It chokes first on the dictionary, then on the functions. Now, I'm struggling with how to incorporate it into the python code. I thought I could write it as a page processor, but I need it to happen for all the blog posts and can't figure out how to do that. I tried writing a page processor for BlogPost, but that's not a subclass of Page, so it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: @raddevon: I'm not familiar with Mezzanine, but if you're using class-based views you could probably customize [`get_context_data`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/) in a base class. Another approach would be to create a simple middleware that inserts the desired value into the request. As for templates, Jinja2 definitely supports accessing dictionary members and calling functions with arguments. It doesn't have a version of `reverse` but if you're using, say, [django-jinja](http://niwibe.github.io/django-jinja/), you can use the equivalent `url()`.